# With svn 1.6 on Mac and https repository svnmerge.py avail says "Could not authenticate to server: rejected Basic challenge"

Tags: svn

I can checkout code from this repository and commit to it, but doing an "svnmerge.py avail" fails with the message

```
svnmerge: command execution failed (exit code: 1)
```

svn --non-interactive propget --strict "svnmerge-integrated" "https://svn.example.org/example/groups.example.org/trunk/sites/all/themes/bluebeach/themes/bluebeach/trunk"
svn: OPTIONS of 'https://svn.example.org/example/groups.example.org/trunk/sites/all/themes/bluebeach/themes/bluebeach/trunk': authorization failed: Could not authenticate to server: rejected Basic challenge (https://svn.example.org)

I'm using svn from collabnet:

```
svn, version 1.6.3 (r38063)
```

Someone suggested this could be because my password is being stored in keychain. I tried removing the information from the keychain but of course it gets added back.

I tried removing the information from keychain and then changing my .subversion/config to say:

```
store-passwords = yes
store-plaintext-passwords = yes
```

but that still sticks them in the keychain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can work around the keychain problem by specifying the username and password as arguments to svnmerge.py:

```
svnmerge.py --username=<username> --password=<pwd> [avail|merge etc.]
```

That fixed it for me.

Comment: I don't like putting my username and password on the command line, but this works and I can just do a "history -c" to clear my bash history.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

To not put the password on the command line as clear text, I have created a little script pw_prompt:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
read -s -p "Password: " pwd; echo $pwd
```

I can then use this in my svnmerge.py commands to interactively request the password without displaying it:

```
$ svnmerge.py --username=<username> --password=$(pw_prompt) init
Password:
```